# Ubuntu Mate 20.10 on Rasberry pi 4 does not recognize 2nd monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I installed the Ubuntu Mate 20.10 desktop for Raspberry pi 4 8Gb and it shows 1 display.
When I go into the display settings it doesn't give the option for a 2nd display.
It does on other OS for the PI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely related to the FKMS overlay loaded. Fortunately it’s not too difficult to resolve.

1. Open the `/boot/firmware/syscfg.txt` For editing:

```
sudo vi /boot/firmware/syscfg.txt
```

2. Add the following line at the bottom of the file:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

3. Reboot

Now you should see both monitors available in Ubuntu.

**Note:**

Sometimes there may be a frame buffer issue that needs to be resolved as well. This can be done by opening the same file as before and adding this:

```
disable_overscan=1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The interesting thing happened I had shut it down from the install yesterday. I booted up this morning and both displays are working now. It's almost like it didn't recognize it until the reboot. But it worked thanks for the reply I will keep it just in case.

Thanks for the reply.